# Convert an array of strings into string literal union type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, generic-type-parameters

I'm trying to convert an array of strings from the value to the string union type inside a function.
But can't achieve it.

Example:

```
const makeGet = (paths: string[]) => (path: typeof paths[number]) => paths.includes(path)
const makeGet2 =
  <T extends string>(paths: string[]) =>
  (path: T) =>
    paths.includes(path)

const routes = ['users', 'todos']
const readonlyRoutes = ['users', 'todos'] as const

const get = makeGet(routes)
const get2 = makeGet2<typeof readonlyRoutes[number]>(routes)

get('users') // no ts support
get2('users') // yes ts support
```

How should I refactor my `makeGet` function to be able to create a string union type from the passed routes array?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwNYFMDiLYF4YAoAOCUAFhAFwzQBOAlmAOYDaAugJQxYB8ehJFUAT3woQAMxi9SjMAFc4AIxRU2HbpIgA6OsAA2MgCYoIBIsVYBYAFChIsRKgxQATByswYAHgAqMFAA8oFDB9CEooWgZOExJyMIimFS43HlMKL3Yky3d3dS0wXQMjaLMrKxtoGCoQGUDQnEYAchkIJQgGgBoYBqgQfRA25jLwCqoUBD6wHQEAJWrajhhG5taOrp6+gZgEUPKoUuth2HpMBft0TFwqmqMLA9sYY+dT5HPnD0FhMUqxianZ64g0jkimUUSutVuVkeuCaLSobXYAHpETAwCAYFBQhAZPh8CAqHtLI8nDD1v0GkiUQIjBisTi8QSgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for:

```
const makeGet =
  <T extends string>(paths: ReadonlyArray<T>) =>
  (path: T) =>
    paths.includes(path);

const routes = ["users", "todos"] as const;

const get = makeGet(routes);

get("users");
get("user"); // Argument of type '"user"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"users" | "todos"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works fine. 

Is it possible to define the array of items outside the function? like in my example?